# Can I remove tiles in niche to re-do?

Tags: shower, tile

Moved into a new house and wow whoever did this niche did not do a great job. I’m pretty handy and want to do something about this. It’s super uneven and just horrible.

I obviously don’t want to redo the entire tiling. I’m a fan of the tiles around it and really just want to fix it. Previous owners said they used a schlüter shower niche. Any ideas on what I can do? Can I dremel the tiles out and reinstall a schlüter system? What about cutting the tiles around the niches and Maybe getting a new niche? one that is a little bigger to fit. Making sure everything is waterproofed? [image]

[image]

Comment: rip that silicone out and see how much that improves the look.

Comment: Do you have any left over tiles? With care you might be able to salvage most tiles, but some will break for sure. Alternately, you might want to replace with different tiles entirely - cost should be minimal for such a small area and you could choose exactly what you want

Answer (score 2):

Rip that silicone out and see how much that improves the look. as for the rest it depends which way that edge trim goes.

Comment: Also wipe a mild acid (vinegar might even be enough) over the grout to clean it up. That should make it look much more tidy

Comment: Clean that trim up too (don't scratch the paint; elbow grease and the *sponge side* of a sponge...). Only reason to touch this w/o gutting the whole thing is that you just can't take the green anymore. Lower left needs some grout too, so might as well clean up all the grout lines. The install is fine; just a crap grout/caulk job. *Grout only*, afterwards; no caulk, it's done its settling.

Comment: Could be that the silicone covers up a gap that the previous person FUBARed!

Comment: it could be that they are lying about the schlüter system, yes.  silicone isn't going to make a tiled surface waterproof.